# Hurting my SEO : My pages DO exist still I am getting 404 status on few pages. Why?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, seo-audit, dead-links

I really need your help in resolving this, my ranking dropped, I diagnosed and it came that there were around 80 - 404 pages in google webmaster tool. They all exist.

Comment: Have you used the "Fetch as Google" feature in Google Webmaster Tools on any of those pages?  What does it say?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller   It fetches. What is the relation in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "fetch as Google" is able to retrieve the pages without errors, then it sounds like Googlebot just hasn't gotten around to re-crawling all the pages yet.    The errors will go away within a couple weeks as Googlebot recrawls the error pages.

You can use the "mark as fixed" feature in Google Webmaster Tools.  It will remove the errors from your list for now.   If Googlebot ever has problems with the pages again when it crawls, it will show you new errors at that point.

Until Google crawls and indexes those particular pages again, they won't get any search traffic.   So it will be hurting your SEO from that standpoint until Google finds them again.

Luckily 404 errors on your site don't hurt your other pages an your site.  [Google's John Mueller says](https://johnmu.com/painful-crawl-errors/):

> **404 errors on invalid URLs do not harm your site’s indexing or ranking** in any way. It doesn’t matter if there are 100 or 10 million, they won’t harm your site’s ranking.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if Google gets 10 million 404s, it will drop-back and punt- meaning that it will want to take a closer look at your site and may possibly start to index the entire site again. For that period, your site will remain stable in the SERPs, however at the end of the re-index, it will very likely recalculate positions as it normally does.